# Preparing for the potential of HTML formatted email - c# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, email, formatting

I'm writing a little email handling applet. It either sends an email (elementary, I know) or replies to a received email. In the latter case, I want to display the original email below the TextBox for the user's message. I have another TextBox there, but I realize that most email clients utilize HTML formatting in one way or another, and this will not display properly in a TextBox.

I don't really have any desire to let the user format their email in some fancy pre-built WYSIWYG editor (most potential solutions I have encountered suggest something of this sort), I just want to allow for the possibility that the received email is formatted with HTML. I'm equally content to strip all HTML formatting from the original message as I am to display the original HTML content in a control other than a TextBox, and append it untouched to the unformatted user input when sending the reply, but I don't see and can't find an elegant way to accomplish either.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just show the HTML if it's text/html and perhaps have a preview button or pane with a WebBrowser in it you can pipe the HTML to.